# What can be the possible causes for "Unknown path components"?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I created a Facebook app and some custom Open Graph Actions and Types.

When i use the sample code from the Open Graph Dashboard to create an action i get the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Unknown path components: \/NAMESPACE:ACTION","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

I am sure i authenticated the app for my account and it has the right permissions to publish actions for that app.

What else can i check or do i have to make sure of that i don't get this error?

Comment: if you're using a versioned url make sure to use vX.X and not just X.X otherwise you'll get this error message